# What does "Press the storm plow to use the shockwave device!" mean?

Tags: steel-storm-burning-retribution

A few times, while playing *Steel Storm: Burning Retribution*, I've seen

> "Press the storm plow to use the shockwave device!"

appear at the top of the screen for a few seconds, seemingly with no trigger, before disappearing.  I've seen no other mention of storm plows or shockwave devices.

What does this mean?